# Project Server 2010 Workflow cannot be updated

Tags: sharepoint, workflow, project-server

I have problem when cretaing branching workflow that is explained in Project Server 2010 SDK.

I managed to create and deploy it at the first time, I update it by changed the title part from Feature1 to feature2 and also I change the stage sequence in the workflow,
then do Retract-Deploy.

The updated workflow is seems to be succeed because the title part is changed feature2, but when I create the new project for the updated workflow, the sequence is still same.

I really appreciate any help for my problem, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem, I had to restsart all Project Server and Sharepoint Server windows services. it was painfull.